# python 3.6 sql database connection

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to insert a row into my postgresql database with a table created from

```
    CREATE TABLE public.coinbase_btc_usd
(
  id bigserial primary key,
  price integer NOT NULL,
  buy integer NOT NULL,
  sell integer NOT NULL,
  "timestamp" timestamp with time zone
)
```

However when my python 3.6 script runs and tries to add a row using psycopg2 like this it returns an error saying "no results to fetch" and nothing is added to my db.

```
        sql_query = "INSERT INTO coinbase_btc_usd(price, buy, sell, timestamp)" \
                " VALUES (" + exchange_rate + ', ' + buy_rate + ', ' + sell_rate + ", \'2015-10-10 06:44:33.8672177\')"

    print(sql_query)

    cur.execute(sql_query)
```

I also printed the sql_query variable to see exactly what was getting attempted to execute and this was printed to the output

```
INSERT INTO coinbase_btc_usd(price, buy, sell, timestamp) VALUES (16392.10, 16563.40, 16235.42, '2015-10-10 06:44:33.8672177')
```

Comment: By the way, your code is subject to sql injection, and you shouldn't be using string concatenation to put values there

Comment: that wasn't my question man... this is all backend and im the only one using it so i doubt im ganna inject myself. I'm just trying to figure out why this last line can't be inserted into a database, i pasted the thing it printedo ut in the console into pgadmin and it inserted just fine

Comment: I'm just saying, there are plenty of examples in the documentation not doing what you are, so why not follow them? http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html

Comment: Not an answer, just a helpful hint, PonyOrm is a pretty simple abstraction that will make working with postgresql much easier ... Inserts require no sql, just python.

Comment: @user1771791 try modifying insert as I show in my answer please and post results. Also injection happens not obviously. If variable value comes not from stdinput, you have a risk of it. Not important if it is some field in a web page or some column value in db. If smbd sees the line above and have indirect way to put injection, it will happen. But of course it is not related to row not inserted. Just after some experience every dev starts to code injection proof statements forany purpose - I can[tforsee thefuture of the code part. You know, just in case. Not obligatory - just everyone does it

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are committing the transaction:

```
cur.execute(sql_query)
conn.commit()
```

Or you can enable auto commit to commit each query immediately after execution:

```
conn.autocommit = True
```

Furthermore, it costs nothing to prevent SQL injection attack - just use parametersied queries. In fact your code will actually be cleaner as well as safer:

```
sql_query = "INSERT INTO coinbase_btc_usd(price, buy, sell, timestamp) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
cur.execute(sql_query, (exchange_rate, buy_rate, sell_rate, timestamp))
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

change the

```
sql_query = "INSERT INTO coinbase_btc_usd(price, buy, sell, timestamp)" \
            " VALUES (" + exchange_rate + ', ' + buy_rate + ', ' + sell_rate + ", \'2015-10-10 06:44:33.8672177\')"
```

to:

```
sql_query = "INSERT INTO coinbase_btc_usd(price, buy, sell, timestamp)" \
            " VALUES (" + exchange_rate + ', ' + buy_rate + ', ' + sell_rate + ", \'2015-10-10 06:44:33.8672177\') returning *"
```

this should fix `no results to fetch` in my assumption.

If you see no row added, you most probably `begin` transaction and never commit it.